# taking an excel file as a input data from user in julia

Tags: input, julia

I want to ask from users to load an excel file as an input data. this process must be done by opening a browsing window to select excel file.
what can I do?

Comment: Perhaps use a web frontend, or some web notebook interface, such as Pluto or Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `open_dialog_native` from Gtk.jl.

```
julia> open_dialog_native("Choose the input Excel file", GtkNullContainer(), ("*.xlsx",))
"/path/to/myfile.xlsx"
```

It opens the file chooser interface appropriate to the user's OS, and once the file is chosen, returns the chosen file's full path as a string.

The `("*.xlsx",)` is a tuple that constrains what type of files are shown by default in the file chooser. (The `GtkNullContainer()` argument just specifies that you're not running this as part of an existing GTK app.)

[Documentation here](https://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/manual/filedialogs/)